# Command to edit formula in QR Report 4dv12

Tags: 4d

I'm writing a method to run a QR report from a 4qr template, and I'm looking for a way to edit a formula in a column without the need to go to Quick Report editor. Couldn't find anything in the documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `QR SET INFO COLUMN` command using a string to pass a formula.
For example:

```
C_TEXT($txtFormula) 
$txtFormula:=”MyMethod(parameter)” 
QR SET INFO COLUMN($myQRArea;1;"Title of Column";$txtFormula;0;-1;1;"")
```